# How to run ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application on Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I developed an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application using Visual Studio 2019 and it is working fine, but when I'm trying to work with the same project in Visual Studio 2022, I get this error :

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

What is required to install to solve this?

Note that when I create a new project with ASP.NET Core 8, it is working fine

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: AFAIK, .NET Core 3.1 is already deprecated. If you insists to run, please make sure you have already downloaded the .NET Core 3.1 SDK. Try to run in console with command; dotnet run.

Comment: There is already .Net Core 3.1 SDK installed

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I changed .net core from 3.1 to 6

Comment: "I gave up" isn't an answer to the original problem

Comment: Ironically, I'm facing the same issue. The old project I need to update is targeting `netcoreapp3.1`. Whenever I try to run it with VS2022, I get the "HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure" error. But if I target .NET 6, it's working fine.